# Command for creating new file / document

Tags: ros, create

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I couldn't create a new file in a folder using ros command line in terminal. Is there any /roscommand for that?

- I can easily create in explorer  for new document
- I can easily create in cpp or python ide.
- I just want to see if I can create without leaving the terminal

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308808/command-for-creating-new-file-/-document/) by [OsManiaC](https://answers.ros.org/users/38586/osmaniac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-11-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-17**:
Does `touch <filename>` do what you want?

This doesn't seem like a ROS question though.

**Comment by [OsManiaC](https://answers.ros.org/users/38586/osmaniac/) on 2018-11-19**:
Thank you, As I mentioned in my question I tried to find if there was a ros command for that. It seems there is not. gedit new_file just works well. Also vi works somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik, there is no "ROS command" to create a new file.

I also believe that would not be very useful:

- it would increase maintenance for ROS (core) maintainers
- managing files is a task for the OS, which has plenty of tools/utilities to do that
- using existing tools instead of introducing something new allows users to reuse their experience and doesn't invalidate their expectations around such tools

A quick way to create a new file in an arbitrary package (in your workspace of course) could be something like:

```
rospd <package_name>
touch my_new_file
rospd
```

To then edit that file:

```
rosed <package_name> my_new_file
```

See also the [rosbash](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbash) documentation.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2